# Catalytic converter heat shield fell off .. Drive home or call tow truck?

Tags: catalytic-converter

One hour drive from home with family.  Heat shield fell from 2007 Honda accord.  Both top and bottom halves of shield rusted from corner bolt.

Safe to finish trip and repair tomorrow, or is the absence of the top shield an imminent hazard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lack of a heat shield is not an imminent hazard. You do want to take a few precautions. First do not park over any flammable objects such as grass, leaves trash etc. Don't place anything on the floor above the converter that may be damaged by the heat like a laptop, digital camera.

Comment: This was timely and helpful.  Stopped at the beach, taking care not to park on grass, and no event.  Could feel no heat through floor of car. Repaired by mechanic today, inexpensive.